# ios - how can I get values from an NSDictionary?

Tags: ios5, ios6, nsdictionary

I am pretty inexperienced with NSDictionary.  I have this data structure:

```
{"aps":
  {"alert":null},
   "custom_control":
    {"type":"topic_comment",
     "object":
        {"topic_id":"1","topic_section":"2","plan_id":"3","user_id":"4"}
    }
}
```

I can potentially get the "aps" value by doing something like this:

```
    NSString *aps = [dictionary objectForKey:@"aps"];
```

But since aps contains an array of items, what data structure should I use instead of NSString? And how do I get the values for custom_control and the values inside "object"

Thank you!

Comment: @Hinata Hyuga sorry I got confused. I do have an NSDictionary object that comes in. I might just not have added the [ ] to my question because I was a bit confused.

Comment: it's not `NSArray` but `NSDictionary`. When you see entity in `()`, it's `NSArray` while in `{}` it's `NSDictionary`. You should take `NSDictionary` rather than `NSString`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
NSDictionary *dict_object = [[dictionary objectForKey:@"custom_control"]objectForKey:@"object"];
```

This is exact hierarchy of your dictionary

Your `NSDictionary(Keys:aps,custom_control)`

```
(i).aps

   (i.i)NSDictionary(key:alert)

(ii).custom_control

   (ii.i)NSDictionary(keys:type,object)

          (ii.i.i)NSString(key:topic_comment)

          (ii.i.ii)NSDictionary(keys:topic_id,topic_section,plan_id,user_id)
```

See this [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDictionary_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: And how do I get the other values inside the object?